# Perl. Информация о свободном пространстве хранилища с помощью модуля HTTP::DAV

Tags: perl, webdav

Работаю с WebDAV Yandex Disk API. Как узнать размер свободного пространства на диске?
[Так](https://tech.yandex.ru/disk/doc/dg/reference/propfind_space-request-docpage/) предлагается сделать в документации API, но в метод propfind (тот, что в модуле) можно передать только параметры depth и url.

Comment: В каком модуле?

Answer (score 1):

Не нашёл такой возможности. В качестве альтернативы можно использовать libcurl для формирования запросов вручную.

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что надо манипулировать не HTTP::DAV напрямую, а по частям. Например, судя по [исходникам](https://metacpan.org/source/COSIMO/HTTP-DAV-0.48/lib/HTTP/DAV/Resource.pm) объекта  [HTTP::DAV::Resource](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::DAV::Resource), он вполне умеет конструировать кастомный запрос в методе `propfind`.